# How to use Nexus IQ CLI?

Tags: homebrew, nexus

I have installed [nexus-iq-cli](https://help.sonatype.com/iqserver/integrations/nexus-iq-cli#NexusIQCLI-Downloads) using homebrew on mac.

Can confirm that it has been installed.

```
Warning: Cask 'nexus-iq-cli' is already installed.

To re-install nexus-iq-cli, run:
  brew reinstall --cask nexus-iq-cli
```

After running

```
./nexus-iq-cli -i my-service -s https://mynexusserver.com/ -a userid:pass -t Build ./
```

I am getting this error

`zsh: no such file or directory: ./nexus-iq-cli`

When i run `brew services` it shows me

```
memcached         none                   
mongodb-community none                   
redis             none                   
unbound           none
```

Is there a step I am missing?